# Apple developer enrollment error: Your enrollment in the Apple Developer Program could not be completed at this time

Tags: ios, apple-developer, user-enrollment

The following message appear when I enroll Apple Developer Program:

> Your enrollment could not be completed.
>
> Your enrollment in the Apple Developer Program could not be completed at this time.

After this message, I can not access payment page.

I asked Apple to solve this problem, but any apple advice can't help.

How can I overcome this? I want to enroll as a Apple developer.

Comment: Same here,,,, since 1week.

Comment: I'm also facing this problem.. Is that Apple Bug?

Comment: Give up is best solution for your mental health. Apple abandoned individual developers

Comment: I will start a bounty, hoping that someone could find a solution.

Comment: Same issue here.

Comment: Same problem... Probably it's a temporary program - too many issues at the same time

Comment: @fedor.belov I don't think so. There are people who facing this problem since 6 months

Comment: same problem here

Comment: same problem and no solution so far

Comment: Same problem... I’ve called apple support but they don’t know how to solve... if they don’t know who will?

Comment: File a bug on Feedback Assistant.app

Comment: @HururuekChapChap Call customer support once, they will solve your issue immediately

Comment: @MdShahnawaz I've called their support, opened 6 cases and the general response has been that they are unable to help. I've tried using my partners details, my sons detauls etc.... and nothing.

Comment: please check with your AppleID email address and the first name and last name you have given. I also faced this issue. please create an apple id with your own personal account and add the organization to that account. this will work

Comment: Same here, really frustrating. I'm trying to build a business here and they have delayed me 3 months with no help, even when I messaged their support countless times. I just wish I knew all that before even developing an app.

Answer (score 17):

I managed to get past this error and successfully enroll.  I hope that the following will help out you and those who follow.

First, I deleted my credit card details from my iCloud account.  To do this on a Mac, go to `Apple Menu > System Preferences`, then select `iCloud`.  Press the `Account Details` button, select the `Payment` tab, press the `Details...` button next to the credit card entry (enter your Apple ID and administrator passwords as requested), then under `Payment method` select `None` and press the `Save` button.

Next, I went back to Apple's Developer website and attempted to re-enroll.  I was very pleased to see the same error message as before:

[image]

Seeing the same error message is helpful.  It indicates that Apple do not give a specific issue even when the credit card details are completely missing.

Next, I re-added identical credit card information to my iCloud account.  To do this on a Mac, go to `Apple Menu > System Preferences`, then select `iCloud`.  Press the `Account Details` button, select the `Payment` tab, press the `Details...` button next to the credit card entry (enter your Apple ID and administrator passwords as requested), then enter your credit card details and press the `Save` button.

Attempting to enroll again allowed me past the "Your enrollment could not be completed" error message.  I then had to deal with my bank blocking the credit card transaction, but that was just a simple phone call to authorize the transaction.  Once authorized, I was very pleased to see:

[image]

I hope this is helpful.  I do strongly feel that Apple could improve the error messages they offer in this scenario.

Comment: Nice. Where are you from?

Comment: New Zealand, if that's helpful.  And I used a New Zealand credit card.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried this solution, but didn't work. Then I realized that my credit contain 20$. So I will try using my friend's credit card because  he uses his credit to pay for apple developer program previouslly. I think this will ensure that there is no backing transctions problems.

Comment: @AhmedShamel Have you considered "crediting" your credit card with the required amount?  In New Zealand it is easy to move say $99 from your transaction account to your credit card.  In this way, if the bill is for $99 you know that your credit limit is not a problem.  It is still possible that the bank blocks the transaction because it considers it potentially fraudulent.

Comment: @MatthewWalker I know that I can crediting my credit card, but I am afraid that apple refuse to accept the payment of my credit card bank (this happened with some developers). So I want to try the safest way. My friend has credit card from discover bank (Bank in US), and he use it to pay for apple developer program subscription.

Comment: For me, there is no way to select None in the payment method dropdown.

Comment: @Abdullah that sounds frustrating!  I'm using OSX10.13.6, so perhaps it's changed in more modern versions?

Comment: @MatthewWalker, I tried the solution. Now a new error message appear. It says: `We are unable to process your request. An unknown error occurred.`
Do you know what this mean?

Comment: @AhmedShamel Interesting.  After you deleted your credit card details and before you re-added them, did you still see the "Your enrollment could not be completed" message?  What error number are you getting back from Apple's server when you see "We are unable to process your request. An unknown error occurred"?  Has the number changed?  When I saw the "Your enrollment could not be completed" message I was getting a result code of 202000.  Sorry I can't be more help.

Comment: @MatthewWalker Sorry for late respond. For the error message `Your enrollment could not be completed.`, the error number was 202000. But now the error message is `We are unable to process your request.` and the error number is 202018

Comment: @AhmedShamel out of interest, if you delete your credit card details and try again, does the error go back to 202000?  If so then I think that's a good sign, it would mean your credit card details were a problem and were fixed when you changed them.  It would also tell others that if they see error number 202000 then they should look into their credit card details specifically.  It would also tell you that error 202018 was a new problem to resolve, but at least it might give you confidence that your new credit card entry was resolving one of the (multiple) issues you had.

Comment: @AhmedShamel Also, you'd think that Apple, with all their billions, would be able to produce error messages that were a little more helpful.  I think we can safely conclude that the Apple developer who was responsible for this could have done a better job!

Comment: @MatthewWalker When the credit deleted again, the same error message still shown (`We are unable to process your request. An unknown error occurred`). This really make me crazy. I tried every possible solution, but still get the same error. In addition, apple stop responding to my emails. It is really unbelievable -_-.

Comment: @AhmedShamel, I think that's a good sign (the repeat of the error, not Apple stopping responding).  The fact that the error repeats tells you that re-adding your credit card details gets rid of *an* error.  The problem is that you have a new error to deal with after that.  If I were in your position, I would try a new credit card (but I don't have much hope for that seeing you said the same card was already successful for your friend).  I think the next step then would be to try creating a new iCloud account from scratch.  If Apple can corrupt credit card data, then perhaps that's not all?

Comment: @MatthewWalker thank you for sharing your experience. It helped me.

Comment: I've been trying for a couple of months, and i havent had any luck - Apple support is basically stating it "is the end of the line, we cannot help you with this". I tried your method and unfortunately it hasn't worked for me. I'll try again in a while to see if it works.

Comment: @user3836415 are you seeing the same error numbers as we saw?  (Numbers 202000, or 202018)?  My plan, if this hadn't worked, was to try another credit card, then to create a new iCloud account and try again.  If you have any luck, please report back.