# All users entering billing retry state

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

We have auto-renewable subscriptions in our app with introductory offer (3 days free trial). The problem is that we experiencing some really strange metrics in our trends reports (Sale and trends). We started our ad campaign with different sources. As a result, we got 500 subscribers with introductory offer. The problem is, that when trial ends, almost all subscribers moves to "Billing retry" state. Almost 95% of all subscribers. It's not a "Cancelled" state, it's exactly problem with billing (Apple cannot charge money from a card or something went wrong with payment). We believe that this is abnormal. A few days after we started a whole new ad campaign with independent new sources. Same result. 90% of subscribers in "Billing retry".

A few tickets to Apple support. Without results. Default responses with public documentation text.Its a new app, so we do not have any metrics to compare with. Does anyone have any idea what it might be? Guys, we really stuck :( Could there be a problem on our side (in code or maybe with AppStoreConnect purchases settings)?

Comment: Isn’t this merely the same well known issue where developers cannot pay Apple, only seen from the user point of view?

Comment: @matt thanks for your answer! I have not heard about this problem. Could please, provide a link where I can read about it? Perhaps it really is the same.

Comment: Well there has been a lot of talk about it on Stack Overflow, even though that is not the correct venue for it. Basically something has gone wrong with Apple's credit card processing. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62442351/apple-developer-enrollment-error-your-enrollment-in-the-apple-developer-program. This sounds like the same thing, only now the user is experiencing it instead of the developer.

Comment: Oh got it. One more think is, that we have another app on this developer account and there is no problem with it. This strange metrics with billing retry persists only for this our particular app.

Comment: @TanyaMarchuk What happens when the "Billing retry" period ends?

Comment: According to Apple, users can be in Billing retry period for 60 days. So we do not have analytics yet. Less than 60 days passed.